# Attribute's value Quick Info not showing in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor

When I hover on Attribute values or C# code inside .razor or cshtml file no Info is showing. However Quick info only works for Attributes (example: @onclick), No other code in these files showing quickinfo.

I tried to click on Quick Info icon in VS toolbar, but it is not enabled by clicking.

I have this problem during several updates to VS, in each update I wait to see this error is fixed but it is not fixed.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You mean for example the popup for the property "Foo" in `<label asp-for="Foo">`?

Comment: for Foo and also for C# codes inside .razor file.

Comment: It may help to show a screenshot. So you get no quick info at all, only for the attributes themselves? I have other problems with the Razor editor, but that's not one of them.

Comment: Due to the limited information you provided. I suggest you first try Tools => Options => Text Editor => C# => check Auto list members (do not check hide advanced members) in Visual Studio.

Then remove the project in the solution, then add the existing project, and re-join the project. Finally restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi, Auto list members is checked. I created a new Blazor Server project (BlazorApp1) with my current settings and the problem exists in the new project. I use VS 2022, 17.6 Preview4.